# Is it possible to delete currentUser firebase authentication user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I used `firebase_auth` package to work with flutter. And I used **phone authentication** to sign in. Everything is working well. But when signout user is not deleted on firebase.

Is it possible to delete firebase user?

```
 RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
         await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
 )
```

I tried this way,
but error is coming..

> delete called null

```
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((currentUser)=>{
             currentUser.delete()
}).onError((e)=>print("Error is $e"));
```

Comment: Do you confirm that you want to **delete** the user when he/she logs out?

Comment: No, Login.. I printed uid too. `currentUser.uid`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You must use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete()` method before (on) `signOut()` method.

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete();
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete the current user after they've signed out, because at that point there is no current user anymore.

But you can prevent this whole chicken-and-egg problem by simply deleting the user without signing out. This should be all that is needed for that:

```
currentUser.delete()
```

You can call this operation "logging out" for your users of course, but in code you're simply deleting their account.